# Оклеить или обклеить?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильнее сказать: оклеить или оБклеить?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оба варианта возможны и равнозначны или почти равнозначны.

Хотя, похоже, есть некоторые стилистические тонкости.
Столб объявлениями - скорее обклеить. А комнату обоями - оклеить. Объяснить не могу.

Answer (score 0):

В Орфоэпическом словаре Резниченко И. Л. даётся только "оклеить". Книга 2004 года. ООО "Издательство Астрель": ООО "Издательство АСТ"  Не могу сказать, почему такое расхождение...

Comment: А [это][1] - глюк или ошибка эксперимента?

[1]: http://dazor.narod.ru/russkie/slovari/reznichenko/orfoepicheskij-reznichenko_643.htm

Comment: "Орфоэпический словарь русского языка: Произношение. Ударение: Ок. 25 000 единиц" / Резниченко Ирина Леонидовна 
 М.: ООО "Издательство Астрель": ООО "Издательство АСТ", 2003. 

За год исчезло слово?

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что "обклеить" скорее характерно для просторечия, так же как и "обделать" вместо "отделать" (комнату, например).

Comment: Это разные вещи. Об в "Обделать" не несет значения воrруг, целиком, в завершенном виде, который есть во всех побобных словах с об: обрезать, обустроить, обнаружить. Сложность только в том, что с "о" тоде возможна форма с тем же заначением.

Comment: behemothus, чем объясните множество опечаток, и как быть?

Answer (score 0):

оттенки смысла разные..оклеили комнату обоями-это покрыли все стены обоями...то есть,покрыть поверхность чем-то..обклеили-это,например, наклеили много чего-то..например,обклеили всю стену афишами..то есть,много афиш наклеили на стены...а если оклеили комнату афишами,то значит,использовали афиши в качестве обоев)))

столб,конечно, обклеили объявлениями))) "Весь столб обклеили..такие-сякие!!!",-ругается дворник,потому что столб не предназначен для объявлений)))

Comment: А, если кратко и с прописной? Без обид, — просто не ясна мысль.

Comment: Если кратко,то "оклеить"-это значит покрыть поверхность полностью. А "обклеить"'это значит наклеить на поверхность много мнопредметов

Comment: Если кратко,то "оклеить"-это значит покрыть поверхность полностью. А "обклеить"'это значит наклеить на поверхность много предметов,иногда слишком много.